Recursive descent JSON parser in Rust
I've written a simple recursive descent JSON parser in Rust. It just reads in a JSON file and prints the syntax tree to the terminal. I'm still learning Rust, and I'd appreciate any review/feedback. Particularly in regard to error handling and idiomatic language, but there could still be bugs lurking around. I've omitted tests for brevity.
lexer.rs
use core::fmt;

use anyhow::{bail, Result};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Token<'a> {
    LeftBrace,
    RightBrace,
    LeftBracket,
    RightBracket,
    Colon,
    Comma,
    Str(&'a str),
    Number(Numeric),
    True,
    False,
    Null,
}

impl fmt::Display for Token<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::LeftBrace => write!(f, "{{"),
            Self::RightBrace => write!(f, "}}"),
            Self::LeftBracket => write!(f, "["),
            Self::RightBracket => write!(f, "]"),
            Self::Colon => write!(f, ":"),
            Self::Comma => write!(f, ","),
            Self::Str(s) => write!(f, "\"{s}\""),
            Self::Number(Numeric::Integer(n)) => write!(f, "{n}"),
            Self::Number(Numeric::Float(n)) => write!(f, "{n}"),
            Self::True => write!(f, "true"),
            Self::False => write!(f, "false"),
            Self::Null => write!(f, "null"),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Numeric {
    Float(f64),
    Integer(i64),
}

pub struct Lexer<'a> {
    json: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    pub fn new(json: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { 
            json,
        }
    }

    pub fn lex(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<Token>> {
        use Token::*;
        let mut tokens: Vec<Token> = vec![];
        loop {
            let mut chars = self.json.chars();
            match chars.next() {
                Some(c) => {
                    match c {
                        '{' => {
                            tokens.push(LeftBrace);
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        '}' => {
                            tokens.push(RightBrace);
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        '[' => {
                            tokens.push(LeftBracket);
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        ']' => {
                            tokens.push(RightBracket);
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        ':' => {
                            tokens.push(Colon);
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        ',' => {
                            tokens.push(Comma);
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        '"' => {
                            let s = self.lex_string()?;
                            tokens.push(Str(s))
                        }
                        '0'..='9' | '-' => {
                            let num = self.lex_number()?;
                            tokens.push(Number(num));
                        }
                        't' if self.json.starts_with("true") => {
                            tokens.push(True);
                            self.json = &self.json["true".len()..];
                        }
                        'f' if self.json.starts_with("false") => {
                            tokens.push(False);
                            self.json = &self.json["false".len()..];
                        }
                        'n' if self.json.starts_with("null") => {
                            tokens.push(Null);
                            self.json = &self.json["null".len()..];
                        }
                        ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' => {
                            self.json = chars.as_str();
                        }
                        c => bail!("Lexing failure on character {c}"),
                    }
                }
                None => {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(tokens)
    }

    fn lex_string(&mut self) -> Result<&'a str> {
        let mut charindices = self.json.char_indices();
        let _ = charindices.next(); // skip first '"'
        let mut escape = false;
        let n;
        loop {
            match charindices.next() {
                None => bail!("Unexpected end of input in string literal"),
                Some((i, '"')) if !escape => {
                    n = i;
                    break;
                }
                Some((_, '\\')) => {
                    escape = true;
                }
                Some(_) => {
                    escape = false;
                }
            }
        }
        let result = &self.json[1..n];
        self.json = charindices.as_str();
        Ok(result)
    }

    fn lex_number(&mut self) -> Result<Numeric> {
        let mut charindices = self.json.char_indices().peekable();
        let mut n = 0;
        let mut floating_point = false;
        if matches!(charindices.peek(), Some((_, '-'))) {
            charindices.next();
        }
        if matches!(charindices.peek(), Some((_, '.')) | Some((_, 'e')) | Some((_, 'E'))) {
            bail!("Invalid numeric literal");
        }
        if matches!(charindices.peek(), Some((_, '0'))) {
            charindices.next().unwrap(); // safe from if condition
            if let Some((_, c)) = charindices.peek() {
                match c {
                    'e' | 'E' | '.' | ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | ',' | ']' | '}' => {}
                    _ => bail!("Invalid numeric literal"),
                }
            }
        } 
        // read integer
        loop {
            match charindices.peek() {
                None => {
                    n = self.json.as_bytes().len();
                    break;
                }
                Some((i, c)) => {
                    match c {
                        '0'..='9' => {
                            charindices.next();
                        }
                        '.' | 'E' | 'e'  => {
                            break;
                        }
                        ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | ',' | ']' | '}' => {
                            n = *i;
                            break;
                        }
                        _ => bail!("Invalid numeric literal"),
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // read fraction
        if matches!(charindices.peek(), Some((_, '.'))) {
            floating_point = true;
            charindices.next();
            loop {
                match charindices.peek() {
                    None => {
                        n = self.json.as_bytes().len();
                        break;
                    }
                    Some((i, c)) => match c {
                        '0'..='9' => {
                            charindices.next();
                        }
                        'e' | 'E' => break,
                        ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | ',' | ']' | '}' => {
                            n = *i;
                            break;
                        }
                        _ => bail!("Invalid numeric literal"),
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // read exponent
        if matches!(charindices.peek(), Some((_, 'e')) | Some((_, 'E'))) {
            floating_point = true;
            charindices.next();
            if matches!(charindices.peek(), Some((_, '+')) | Some((_, '-'))) {
                charindices.next();
            }
            loop {
                match charindices.peek() {
                    None => {
                        n = self.json.as_bytes().len();
                        break;
                    }
                    Some((i, c)) => match c {
                        '0'..='9' => {
                            charindices.next();
                        }
                        ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | ',' | ']' | '}' => {
                            n = *i;
                            break;
                        }
                        _ => bail!("Invalid numeric literal"),
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        let result = if floating_point {
            let res = self.json[0..n].parse::<f64>()?;
            Ok(Numeric::Float(res))
        } else {
            let res = self.json[0..n].parse::<i64>()?;
            Ok(Numeric::Integer(res))
        };
        self.json = &self.json[n..];
        result
    }
} 

parser.rs
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::iter::Peekable;
use std::slice::Iter;
use anyhow::{bail, Result};
use crate::lexer::Token;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum JsonTree<'a> {
    Object(HashMap<&'a str, JsonTree<'a>>),
    Array(Vec<JsonTree<'a>>),
    Atom(Token<'a>),
}

pub struct Parser { }

impl<'a> Parser {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { }
    }

    pub fn parse(&'a self, vec: &'a [Token]) -> Result<Option<JsonTree>> {
        self.value(&mut vec.iter().peekable())
    }

    fn value(&'a self, iter: &mut Peekable<Iter<Token<'a>>>) -> Result<Option<JsonTree>> {
        match iter.peek() {
            Some(Token::LeftBrace) => {
                match self.object(iter) {
                    Ok(object) => Ok(Some(object)),
                    Err(e) => Err(e.context("In parsing of object")),
                }
            }
            Some(Token::LeftBracket) => {
                match self.array(iter) {
                    Ok(array) => Ok(Some(array)),
                    Err(e) => Err(e.context("In parsing of array"))
                }
            }
            Some(Token::Str(s)) => {
                iter.next();
                Ok(Some(JsonTree::Atom(Token::Str(s))))
            }
            Some(Token::Number(n)) => {
                iter.next();
                Ok(Some(JsonTree::Atom(Token::Number(*n))))
            }
            Some(Token::True) => {
                iter.next();
                Ok(Some(JsonTree::Atom(Token::True)))
            }
            Some(Token::False) => {
                iter.next();
                Ok(Some(JsonTree::Atom(Token::False)))
            }
            Some(Token::Null) => {
                iter.next();
                Ok(Some(JsonTree::Atom(Token::Null)))
            }
            None => Ok(None),
            Some(t) => bail!("Unexpected token {t:?}"),
        }
    }

    fn object(&'a self, iter: &mut Peekable<Iter<Token<'a>>>) -> Result<JsonTree> {
        iter.next(); // consume left brace
        let mut elements: HashMap<&str, JsonTree> = HashMap::new();
        if matches!(iter.peek(), Some(Token::RightBrace)) {
            return Ok(JsonTree::Object(elements));
        }
        loop {
            let name = match iter.next() {
                Some(Token::Str(s)) => s,
                t => bail!("Invalid token {t:?}"),
            };
            match iter.next() {
                Some(Token::Colon) => {}
                Some(t) => bail!("Expected ':' but found {:?}", t),
                None => bail!("Unexpected end of input"),
            }
            let member = match self.value(iter) {
                Ok(Some(value)) => value,
                Ok(None) => bail!("Unexpected end of input"),
                Err(e) => return Err(e.context("In object member definition")),
            };
            elements.insert(name, member);
            if matches!(iter.peek(), Some(Token::Comma)) {
                iter.next();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        let token = iter.next();
        if !matches!(token, Some(Token::RightBrace)) {
            bail!("Expected }}, got {token:?}");
        }
        Ok(JsonTree::Object(elements))
    }

    fn array(&'a self, iter: &mut Peekable<Iter<Token<'a>>>) -> Result<JsonTree> {
        iter.next();
        let mut elements = Vec::new();
        if matches!(iter.peek(), Some(Token::RightBracket)) {
            iter.next();
            return Ok(JsonTree::Array(elements));
        }
        loop {
            let element = match self.value(iter) {
                Ok(Some(value)) => value,
                Ok(None) => bail!("Unexpected end of input"),
                Err(e) => return Err(e.context("In array definition")),
            };
            elements.push(element);
            if matches!(iter.peek(), Some(Token::Comma)) {
                iter.next();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        let token = iter.next();
        if !matches!(token, Some(Token::RightBracket)) {
            bail!("Expected ] but got {token:?}");
        }
        Ok(JsonTree::Array(elements))
    }
}

main.rs
use std::io::Read;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::process::exit;
use std::fs::File;
use anyhow::Result;

use clap::Parser;
use lexer::Lexer;
use parser::Parser as MyParser;

mod lexer;
mod parser;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let args = Args::parse();
    let mut file = match File::open(&args.path) {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => { 
            println!("Encountered error opening file {}: {e}", args.path.to_str().unwrap());
            exit(-1);
        }
    };
    let mut contents = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut contents) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Encountered error reading file {}: {e}", args.path.to_str().unwrap());
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    let mut lexer = Lexer::new(&contents);
    let tokens = lexer.lex()?;
    let parser = MyParser::new();
    match parser.parse(&tokens) {
        Ok(Some(tree)) => {
            println!("{tree:?}")
        }
        Ok(None) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error parsing {}: {e}", args.path.to_str().unwrap());
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

// Simple JSON parser
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    // The input file path
    path: PathBuf,
}


You implementation appears incomplete. E.g. "NaN" cannot be parsed while it should be valid.

Main
Error Handling
You error handling is really not great:

Errors should be printed to stderr, not stdout.
Pattern matching + println! + exit is very verbose.

You're really not using the strengths of anyhow here!
Instead, consider using:

.with_context to attach context.
? to propagate the error upwards.

As in:
let mut file = File::open(&args.path)
    .with_context(|| format!("Failed to open '{}'", args.path.to_str().unwrap()))?;

Much more concise!
Factorization
Considering factorizing args.path.to_str().unwrap() into a variable, or at least providing a simple getter on Args that does the job.
Non UTF-8 Paths
The reason that unwrap is necessary in args.path.to_str().unwrap() is that not all paths are valid UTF-8 (filesystems don't care). If the unwrap panics, then you'll get the message and backtrace of the unwrap, and lose the error message you were trying to print... which is sad.
Instead, since this is for display purposes, consider using .to_string_lossy().
Lexer
Memory Allocation!
Why lex in a Vec?
You should be able to parse JSON with O(1) lookahead, which means you shouldn't need a Vec. Instead, your Lexer could implement the Iterator trait, and provide token one at a time, until it can't.
(Or an error, of course, which would also be the last thing it produces)
This is especially vexing as the parser immediately turns the Vec into an iterator...
Bytes! It's just Bytes!
First of all, it would be cool if the lexer could consume bytes without first validating at the UTF-8 level.
But more importantly, parsing via .chars() costs you quite a bit of performance:

.chars() has to reconstitute a char from a stream of bytes.
You then match on a 32-bits char instead of an 8-bits byte.

I would encourage you to use .as_bytes() instead, and parse byte by byte. All the delimiters you need to match are single-byte, after all.
And you can still sub-slice on the base &str when producing an &str, to avoid having to re-validate that it's UTF-8 all the way through.
Built-in search!
&str has a built-in search function which is likely better optimized than your char by char loop.
It's not very well-documented, unfortunately, but you can search by an array (or slice) of char and get the index of the first matching byte in the string, that is:
let mut rest = &self.json[1..];

while let Some(n) = rest.find(['\\', '"']) {
    let byte = rest.as_bytes()[n];

    assert!(byte == b'\\' || byte == b'"');
}

Hopefully, behind the scenes it uses an accelerated vectorized search. Otherwise, consider the memchr crate, and specifically its memchr2 function to search for the end of the string.
Redundant number parsing
You are very carefully evaluating each number char by char, only to then call the standard library parsing routine.
The standard library parsing routine will parse the number, and validate each char in turn, so all your work is quite redundant really.
Instead, you only really need to figure out where the end of the number is. This is the first byte that is neither . nor ASCII digit.
Unfortunately memchr cannot help here because there's two many terminating characters (space, tab, carriage return, feed return, }, ], ,) so a simple str.find by predicate (neither . nor ASCII digit) is the easiest, if not necessarily the fastest.
And once you have the range, it's a simple matter of figuring out whether there's a . in there, which memchr can help with, to know whether it's a float or an integral.
Float or Integral
An interesting conundrum with relying on "flags" of floats to determine whether to parse as float (or not) is that a number can be an integral, yet not fit in an i64 (or u128 for that matter).
One technique to deal with such overflows would be to attempt to parse a would-be integer as an integral, but fall back to f64 on overflow.
Parser
Tighten up the model!
That Atom(Token<'_>) may feel slick, but it's really unfortunate.
Imagine the poor consumer of this API: they'll need to match on LeftBrace, RightBrace, etc... all the time even though those should never be there!
I would advise just accepting your fate, and either creating a new Atom enum, or just enumerating all cases in JSonTree.
A tight type is a type which can only represent valid values!
Equality is more readable than matches!
Consider:
if matches!(iter.peek(), Some(Token::RightBrace)) { ... }
if iter.peek() == Some(Token::RightBrace) { ... }
if !matches!(iter.peek(), Some(Token::RightBrace)) { ... }
if iter.peek() != Some(Token::RightBrace) { ... }

The only think you need to be able to write the equality, is to derive PartialEq on Token, and you may as well derive Eq while you are at it. It's free.
Parsing Stack Overflow
It's not clear whether you'll care, but it's worth touching upon in general when talking about parsers.
In the case of a very deeply nested JSON, unbounded recursion in the code may lead to a Stack Overflow, terminating the thread. You could argue it's a fine, and that the user can just use a thread with a sufficiently large stack.
Or you could change how the parser works to use a manual stack instead. At the very least, it's a fairly interesting exercise.
Model Stack Overflow
And of course, if you have a very deeply nested JSON, you end up with a very deeply nested JsonTree, whose Drop implementation may overflow.
To avoid the issue, you would need to write a custom Drop implementation for JsonTree, which doesn't recurse.
Hint 1:

 The simplest implementation is to just use a stack of JsonTree.

Hint 2:

 Create a Vec, push all the elements/fields (if any) of self into it. Then pop from the Vec, again push all the elements/fields (if any) into it. Go back to popping.

